# Unable to authorize on Facebook with fbconsole

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I just install [Dean Malmgren's fork of fbconsole lib](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/fbconsole), and try his `fbconsole.automatically_authenticate` function to authenticate on Facebook but with no luck. I just get this error message:

```
/var/virtualenvs/jd/src/fbconsole/src/fbconsole.pyc in automatically_authenticate(username, password, app_secret, redirect_uri, debug)
    411         oauth["state"][0], state,
    412     )
--> 413     code = oauth["code"][0]
    414 
    415     # 4. Exchange the code for a user access token for this user's data


KeyError: 'code'
```

I don't know what is wrong. I have suspicion, that there could be some problem with Facebook app settings (for example I am not able to set Site URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` value). I try run this code on localhost and also on production server. But the error is still same (Facebook didn't give me the `code` parameter).

Does anybody know where could be the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

oauth doesn't have 'code' parameter because on previous step we get error from facebook because we used expired APP_ID (that was defined in fbconsole).

correct usage of fbconsole.automatically_authenticate:

```
import fbconsole.py
fbconsole.APP_ID = 'our APP_ID'
fbconsole.automatically_authenticate('LOGIN','PASS','our APP_SECRET','request_uri')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `site_url` to `http://local.fbconsole.com:8080/`
Then use this code to authenticate

```
import fbconsole as fb
fb.APP_ID = <your app id in quotes> 
fb.AUTH_SCOPE = <any list of scopes>
fb.authenticate()
```